# Class method interaction with static and const

Tags: c++, oop, class, methods

Code:

```
   #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class Item
    {
        int num;
    public:
        Item(int i) : num(i) {};
        int getNum() const { return num; }
    };

    class ItemPool
    {
    public:
        Item* getItem (int);
    };

    Item* ItemPool::getItem (int n)
    {
        static Item myX(0);
        if (n%2) return &myX;
        else return new Item(n);
    }

    void main()
    {
        ItemPool coll;
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
                  Item* anX = coll.getItem(i);
                  cout<<anX->getNum()<<’\n’;
        }
    }
```

Question:

1)   Which **semantic** problem in execution does this program have?

2)   Change only the main() function so that the behavior of the program remains the same, but that this problem is eliminated.

Thanks!!

Comment: This looks like homework, but isn't marked as such.

Comment: `main()` always returns `int`, regardless of what Microsoft's IDE's do. Break that habit!

Comment: @VaughnCato it's just me preparing for an exam, it's not homework... if it were I would've marked it as such :)

Comment: @Vidak: I'm not sure about the specific policy in that case, but I think it would be a good idea to mark it as homework anyway.  At the very least, it would be a good idea to state in your question that this is a question from a book and be specific about where you are having difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantic problem is that the `ItemPool::getItem()` method can return a pointer to either a dynamically allocated object, or a static one. It is not clear who takes ownership of the dynamically allocated object, and the caller has no way of knowing if they have to deallocate the object or not, without knowing the details of the implementation of the `ItemPool::getItem()`.

I see no way of changing eliminating the problem *and* keeping the program behaviour the same. The program behaviour is erroneous, so fixing the problem would change its behaviour.

You can modify `main()` to deallocate `Items` when `i%2==0` after the `cout`. But that would change the behaviour of the program, in that there would no longer be a memory leak.

```
void main()
{
  ItemPool coll;
  for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
  {
    Item* anX = coll.getItem(i);
    std::cout << anX->getNum() << "\n";
    if (i%2) == 0 delete anX;
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree with your general assessment, but perhaps the assignment is to see that there is a memory leak and avoid it by only changing main.

Comment: @VaughnCato perhaps, but that would change the behaviour of the program :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza yeah, I'm sure that the edited version of main is what was needed :) thanks!

Comment: "*I see no way of changing eliminating the problem and keeping the program behaviour the same.*" Return a `shared_ptr<Item>`.

Comment: @ildjarn it would change the behaviour of the program *and* it would involve more than a modification to `main()`. The first point may be me just being facetious, but the second clearly violates requirement of the question.

Comment: Sorry, I was ignoring "*Change only the main() function*" for the moment and just nitpicking that sentence. ;-]